# How to change logos in Black color by using bclogo.sty

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, bclogo

Is this possible to change `\bclampe` color to Black color? My tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{environ} %fancy boxes
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes,arrows,calc,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,graphs,positioning,fit,petri}
\tikzstyle{cuadricula}=[gray ,thick,dashed] %style for tike grids
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\NewEnviron{myidea}[1]
  {\par\medskip\noindent
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (box) {\parbox[t]{.99\textwidth}{%
      \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
      \centering\tikz[scale=5]\node[scale=2,rotate=30]{\bclampe};
      \end{minipage}%
      \begin{minipage}{.65\textwidth}
      \textbf{#1}\par\smallskip
      \BODY
      \end{minipage}\hfill}%
    };
    \draw[black,line width=3pt]
      ( $ (box.north east) + (-5pt,3pt) $ ) -- ( $ (box.north east) + (0,3pt) $ ) -- ( $ (box.south east) + (0,-3pt) $ ) -- + (-5pt,0);
    \draw[black,line width=3pt]
      ( $ (box.north west) + (5pt,3pt) $ ) -- ( $ (box.north west) + (0,3pt) $ ) -- ( $ (box.south west) + (0,-3pt) $ ) -- + (5pt,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}\par\medskip%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myidea}{Title}
This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. 
This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. 
This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. 
This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. 
\end{myidea}

\end{document}
```

PS: I need to get all logos in Black color only...

Comment: @schtandard It's not a duplicate, there is a real answer.

Comment: @AndréC Well, it's not impossible to answer duplicate questions. The answer is the same, as well: "LaTeX can't do that for you, you need to change the image with an external editor."

Comment: @schtandard The difference here is that the logos provided in the package can be modified with metapost. This has nothing to do with includegraphics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logos in `bclogo` are drawn with Metapost.

Find `bc-lampe.mp` on your system. Copy it to your working directory as `bc-lampe-bw.mp`.

Open the file and change

```
drawoptions (withcolor (1.000000,1.000000,0.000000));
```

into

```
drawoptions (withcolor (1.000000,1.000000,1.000000));
```

This is where yellow is used, changed into white.

Run Metapost on the file.

In your document, add

```latex
\newcommand{\bclampebw}{\includegraphics[width=\logowidth]{bc-lampe-bw}}
```

and in your code change `\bclampe` to `\bclampebw`.

[image]

This is the file `bc-lampe-bw.mp` (already with the change)

```
prologues:=1;
outputtemplate:="%j.mps";
beginfig(1);
linecap := butt;
fill (7.386720,3.144530)--(9.726560,3.144530)--(9.726560,5.484380)
    --(7.386720,5.484380)--cycle;
pickup pencircle scaled 0.600000bp;
draw (7.386720,3.144530)--(9.726560,3.144530)--(9.726560,5.484380)
    --(7.386720,5.484380)--cycle;
drawoptions (withcolor (1.000000,1.000000,1.000000));
pickup pencircle scaled 0.000000bp;
fill (9.726560,5.484380)--(9.726560,6.261720)..controls (9.726560,8.601560) and (10.894500,8.992190)..(11.675800,10.160200)
    ..controls (12.843800,12.109400) and (12.066400,15.621100)..(8.558590,15.621100)
    ..controls (5.046880,15.621100) and (4.269530,12.109400)..(5.437500,10.160200)
    ..controls (6.218750,8.992190) and (7.386720,8.601560)..(7.386720,6.261720)
    --(7.386720,5.484380)--cycle;
drawoptions (withcolor (0.000000,0.000000,0.000000));
pickup pencircle scaled 0.600000bp;
draw (9.726560,5.484380)--(9.726560,6.261720)..controls (9.726560,8.601560) and (10.894500,8.992190)..(11.675800,10.160200)
    ..controls (12.843800,12.109400) and (12.066400,15.621100)..(8.558590,15.621100)
    ..controls (5.046880,15.621100) and (4.269530,12.109400)..(5.437500,10.160200)
    ..controls (6.218750,8.992190) and (7.386720,8.601560)..(7.386720,6.261720)
    --(7.386720,5.484380);
draw (6.609380,4.312500)--(10.507800,4.312500);
pickup pencircle scaled 0.200000bp;
draw (8.558590,3.535160)..controls (8.945310,7.042970) and (8.167970,10.160200)..(10.117200,11.722700)
    ..controls (9.335940,12.890600) and (7.386720,12.500000)..(6.996090,11.722700)
    ..controls (8.945310,10.160200) and (8.167970,7.042970)..(8.558590,3.535160);
pickup pencircle scaled 0.600000bp;
draw (4.660160,16.007799)--(2.320310,18.347700);
draw (8.558590,17.570299)--(8.558590,20.296900);
draw (12.457000,15.621100)--(14.882800,17.660200);
draw (13.625000,12.890600)--(15.964800,12.890600);
draw (3.488280,12.890600)--(0.761719,12.890600);
r:=17pt/(xpart(urcorner(currentpicture))-xpart(ulcorner(currentpicture)));
picture pic;
pic:=currentpicture;
currentpicture:=nullpicture;
drawoptions();
draw pic scaled(r);
z0=.5*urcorner(currentpicture)+.5*ulcorner(currentpicture);
z1=.5*lrcorner(currentpicture)+.5*llcorner(currentpicture);
draw (z0+(10.5,2));
draw (z1-(10.5,2));
clip currentpicture to ((z0-(8.5pt,0))--(z0+(8.5pt,0))--(z1+(8.5pt,-2pt))--(z1-(8.5pt,2pt))--cycle);
endfig;
end
```

As far as I can see, `bclogo` is released under LLPL 1.3, so changing a file is allowed (also changing the name, which is not required, but preferred).

Comment: On MikTeX there is only the file `bc-lampe.mps` on the folder `\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\bclogo`. It dont have the line `drawoptions (withcolor (1.000000,1.000000,0.000000));`

Comment: @AndréC You could download it from CTAN, but I spared you the business.

Comment: @AndréC on my system they are in `metapost/bclogo` (but I'm using TeXLive which comes with everything)

Comment: @egreg Great thanks you :)

Comment: @egreg Thanks, it's working fantastically, I need to convert all  `tikz` logos (e.g., `\bcdanger`, etc.) into Black color, is there any global possibilities avaliable? advise..

Comment: @MadyYuvi I don't think there is another method other than modifying the colors in all the sources.

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot for your valuable support....

Comment: @MadyYuvi this is not TikZ, but Metapost logos...

Comment: @AndréC Thanks for your notification...

Comment: @egreg I have modified all the logos as per your instruction, now got the Black color visually, but in `Pitstop professional` shows that Black color as combination of `RGB/CMYK`, is it possible to fix pure Black? Sorry for giving more trouble. Note that I'm using `PDFLaTeX` in `MikTeX V2.9`